# Most demanding German Newspapers

Tags: language-cultivation

I'd like to know if there's any relevant distinction among German newspapers with respect to the sophistication of the use of language (both syntax- and vocabulary-wise). I've seen in numerous websites that FAZ, ZEIT and SZ are the most renownd German newspapers and I've seen numerous comments on their respective political tendencies, but I've yet to see someone comment on the quality of the use of the German language in each of these.

Comment: Are really asking for "most demanding" (i.e. difficult), or are you interested in something else? E.g. most attention to good style, or whatever?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Both things interest me, I'd like to read journalistic pieces that were written with the same quality that would be found in a good book. :) Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: Geht es um deutsche Zeitungen oder um deutschsprachige? Die NZZ gilt als von gewisser Qualität, erst mit Abstand folgt die FAZ, bei anderen Produkten ist die Qualität bestenfalls durchwachsen. Oft ist der Zustand mit beklagenswert noch geschönt beschrieben.

Comment: @userunknown Sure, I meant to ask about Newspapers written in German in general!

Comment: Not really meant serious: "Der Postillion" is a online-newspaper which is very fastidious with it's humor, irony, sarcasm but most of all its creative play on words and language. ;-)

Comment: You can also add _Der Freitag_ into the mix.

Comment: Your question is not suitable. There is no metric for this. Where are you from? In your origin are there newspapers rated like this in any way?

Comment: @userunknown Sag mal, meinst du das ernst mit Deiner Bewertung? Nach welchen Richtlinien bewertest du die Qualität? Das ist ja wohl äußerst subjektiv. Die Bild-Zeitung ist auch bekannt für eine äußerst adäquate Widerspiegelung der "einfachen" deutschen Sprache.

Comment: @Thomas Granted, I don't think there's a metric for this, but it seems to me that people can share reasonably grounded impressions to this matter (I've even seen so called "Medienlandschaft" charts in which newspapers are categorised according to political orientation and complexity (granted, I don't know how reliable that's supposed to be). I don't know if there's such thing in my home country either (I find our newspapers to be tedious tbh).

Comment: @Beneficium You will maybe find such categorization in a more scientific context but without to be claimed as a generic reference. If someone publishes such a categorization she/he should always publish a disclaimer which exlpains this. This forum here is not the right place to give such a recommendation because it is rather opinion based. By the way there are complex cultural reasons why such a metric does not exist. But this is a big discussion too complex to dicuss here. If you want to know more I recommend to start a discussion in Meta.

Comment: @Thomas  There are many things in language that cannot be assessed by "metrics". If this is  a criterion, you can shut down virtually the entire forum here.

Comment: @Thomas: Grundlage der Bewertung sind Fehler aller Art und schlechter Stil. Dass die Bildzeitung für eine adäquate Widerspiegelung der einfachen, deutschen Sprache bekannt ist, behauptet sie nicht mal selbst. Das ist Humbug und wird durch Anführungsstriche um "einfache", deren Bedeutung man wohl erraten soll, kaum zu heilen sein. Selbst wenn es so wäre, ist mit authentischer Proletensprache wohl kaum die Qualität gemeint, nach der gefragt war.

Comment: IMHO, it's absolutely possible to give an answer that is based on facts and not on opinion. There is no perfect metric, but that doesn't mean that there are no good answers. One could measure the average number of different words per article of a certain length, the total number of different words used in the last few years, the average length of a sentence, the average number of side clauses, usage of idioms or any pattern that makes reading difficult for children or language learners. Surprisingly, though, I didn't find a single scientific article with such a comparison.

Answer (score 4):

The originality of the *die Tageszeitung ([die taz](http://taz.de))* would make it a little bit more demanding than the average.

Answer (score 4):

The weekly news magazine *Der Spiegel* has recently reaffirmed its reputation for delivering beautifully written inventive pieces.

Comment: ... whereas over decades it was ill-renouned for its variuos mannerisms.

Comment: …[which led to some problems with the factual basis of some too “inventive” texts](https://uebermedien.de/33962/der-spiegel-und-die-gefaehrliche-kultur-des-geschichten-erzaehlens/). (Sorry, off-topic, I know.)

Comment: @David Vogt Is there a certain piece you're talking about? At least in pre anti-adblock-times Der Spiegel was abysmal.

Comment: @npst The answer is probably referring to the affair around their journalist Claas Relotius.

Comment: @npst  ... the public outcry about which is, in my eyes, rather hypocritical, as Relotius' creative handling of pesonnel in his stories was simply an answer to a strong demand for exactly such stories. Had he been given time enough for research, he would have found those testimonials he - economically - invented.

Comment: @npst  Another very famous case was that of **Tom Kummer**, a Swiss journalist who sent absolutely brilliant interviews from New York, Holywood etc. with top-celebrities. These interviews were very well written and got published in the most prestiguous places, e.g. as cover stories of *Süddeutsche Magazin*. Actually, right when I read the first interviews I personally became aware of (with **Liv Taylor**) I thought: "Wow! How did he make that girl talk such interesting things!" - That was about in 2000. Exactly in that year it was revealed that all these interviews were simply invented. :-)

Comment: PS: He actually could simply have left a note underneath like "Attention. This interview is fiction. For writing it I collected available information on the interviewee and then, based on this, compiled a text I knew would be approved by my editors and liked by readers." He did not, and therefore his art was seen as fraud. (Of course, his art also would not have been published in that places, and paid so well.)

Comment: @npst *pre anti-adblock-times Der Spiegel*: spiegel.de is actually Spiegel Online, which »wurde am 25. Oktober 1994 als redaktionell unabhängiges Web-Angebot des Nachrichtenmagazins Der Spiegel gegründet« (Wikipedia) and thus only rarely publishes actual Der Spiegel texts.

Comment: This comment section is full of knowledge :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for extremes - and "most demanding" suggests you are - than try reviews of classical concerts in any of the big papers, and (IMHO) in particular in the FAZ. But don't take them as examples. It is a special style that would sound outright ridiculuous in any other context. Sometimes it feels just like a competition in inventing words and phrases.

The ZEIT and the Süddeutsche Magazin both have crosswords that are largely based on play of words. Probably quite demanding for a non-native speaker, too.

As for the "normal" texts, in my opinion the differences among good and bad texts (from a language perspective) in any one of the papers you mentioned (plus WELT and SPIEGEL) are bigger than the differences of the average level (whatever this should be) of these papers. So you can safely select them by their quality of journalism (which is out of scope here) and will get more or less the same language level.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to read well-written pieces (both in terms of style and journalistic genre), I recommend having a look at Page 3 (*Die Seite Drei*) of the *Süddeutsche Zeitung* daily.

There you find (not every day but very often) true masterpieces of journalism. Not standard stuff from the journalistic word mill, rather things that focus on background and are written to last as literature; things that can be amusing and enlightening to read even if you are not interested in the actual topic of the narrative.

Some of the authors have also published books with their "Seite 3" pieces. My favourite was always the old master of ironic reporting, Herbert Riehl-Heyse, who unfortunately died, much too young, in 2003. I recommend especially:

> Herbert Riehl-Heyse: Die Weihe des Ersatzkaisers und andere Geschichten. Basel 1986.

You find this book currently at prieces starting from 1 euro at many second hand book traders. And here is a link to one of the pieces from the book: http://reporter-forum.de/fileadmin/pdf/Gern_Gelesen/riehl-heise_wortgekringel.pdf (link checked 2019-02-26).

Also:

> Herbert Riehl-Heyse: Das tägliche Gegengift. Reportagen und Essays 1972 - 2003. München 2008.
>
> Herbert Riehl-Heyse: Bestellte Wahrheiten. Anmerkungen zur Freiheit eines Journalistenmenschen. München 1989 (Kindler).

---

PS: I read the article about the Klagenfurt journalist award right now again. Yes, this is indeed *demanding*. You need, I believe, a very high level of understanding of German, including text genres, and various registers of speech, in order to feel the irony in it. It sometimes hides in nothing else but the way a sentence is built.